# Nvidia-440 Driver is installed on Ubuntu 20.04, but won't run

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, 20.04

My installation of the nvidia-440 driver (the recommended one for my system) seems to have worked just fine, but my system refuses to actually *run* it. I installed it using `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and everything checks out.

```
$ prime-select query         
nvidia
```

```
$ sudo apt list --installed | grep "nvidia*"

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libnvidia-cfg1-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-common-440/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-compute-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-compute-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-container-tools/now 1.1.1-1 amd64 [installed,local]
libnvidia-container1/now 1.1.1-1 amd64 [installed,local]
libnvidia-decode-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-decode-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-encode-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-encode-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-extra-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-fbc1-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-fbc1-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-gl-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-gl-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-ifr1-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-ifr1-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-compute-utils-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-dkms-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-driver-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-kernel-common-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-kernel-source-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-prime/focal,focal,now 0.8.14 all [installed,automatic]
nvidia-settings/focal,now 440.64-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-utils-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440/focal-updates,focal-security,now 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Here is my specific system device:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001CBAsv00001028sd00000831bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP107GLM [Quadro P2000 Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

But when I check, this is what I see:

```
 
$ nvidia-smi                 
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP107GLM [Quadro P2000 Mobile] driver: N/A 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: fbdev unloaded: modesetting,vesa 
  resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics P630 (CFL GT2) 
  v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8
```

```
$ nvidia-settings            

ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:14641): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:56:30.855: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 11:56:30.858: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: 11:56:30.858: PRIME: is it supported? yes
** Message: 11:56:30.879: PRIME: Usage: /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia|intel|on-demand|query
** Message: 11:56:30.879: PRIME: on-demand mode: "1"
** Message: 11:56:30.879: PRIME: is "on-demand" mode supported? yes
```

My computer still seems to be using my Intel card:

```
$ lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3e94] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GLM [Quadro P2000 Mobile] [10de:1cba] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

I've edited grub, disabled nouveau and wayland, pretty much done everything I can think of. Can you help me?

Comment: Did you check and make sure that Secure Boot is disabled in BIOS?

Comment: You can uninstall all nvidia related packages and just install the `nvidia-driver-440` again and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes, secure boot is off. I've tried un- and re-installing a few times but I'll give it another go, why not :)